# How to change message dialog text font at runtime in uwp?

Tags: localization, uwp, messagedialog

I am developping a kiosk app for people come from diffrent countries, UI language should be changed at runtime.

`ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride` can change the text and font shown in pages, but no effect for content in a message dialog, dialogs always shown in a font for the default language.

Some language should not be shown in a font for another language, just like Chinese text should not be shown in a Japanese font.

Is there a way to change the dialog font at runtime, just like `ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride` property for pages?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a **Class Language**, define there a **string Lcid** (you may google what is LCID) and **List** of strings **Texts**.

Create a static method that will return you all your texts in different languages and fill it:

```
public class Language
{
    public string Lcid { get; set; }
    public List<string> Texts { get; set; }

    public static List<Language> GetLanguages()
    {
        return new List<Language>
        {
            new Language
            {
                Lcid = "uk",
                Texts = new List<string>
                {
                    "Привіт",
                    "Бувай"
                }
            },
            new Language
            {
                Lcid = "en",
                Texts = new List<string>
                {
                    "Hello",
                    "Bye"
                }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

In your UserControl:

```
    private readonly List<Language> _languages = Language.GetLanguages();
    private List<string> _currentLanguageTexts = new List<string>();
```

Now you may switch your languages by comparing current LCID and set **Texts** to the **_currentLanguageTexts** that should be **x:Bind**ed in your XAML.